# How can I dynamically set a search form with a different route in Rails views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have a very simple form for search written in HAML:

```
%form.search{ method: 'get', action: '/users/search' }
...
```

What would be the correct rails conventions for rendering a different search route based on the model that the controller sets in an instance variable when rendering this view?

I found this [blog post](http://www.rymcmahon.com/articles/2), but this code `<%= form_tag(recipes_path, :method => "get"` is not generic enough for me. I would like to set this value, `recipes_path`, based on the model that the controller is collaborating with when it renders this view. The search form could be used across multiple controllers with their own search action. My app can search on different pages for different models.

I can definitely come up with a way to do it, but I would like to know the 'right' way or I suppose the 'rails' way of dynamically setting the form action to a different controller action based on the data that the form will be searching against.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the 'right' or 'rails' way of doing this is. (But, it sure isn't hand-crafting a form with `%form`.)

In my apps, I tend to only have one form partial that looks something like this:

`app/views/widgets/form`

```
- @presenter = local_assigns[:presenter] if local_assigns[:presenter]

= form_tag @presenter.form_path, remote: true, id: @presenter.form_id, class: @presenter.form_classes, data: @presenter.form_data, method: @presenter.form_method do 
    = @presenter.form_inner
```

In my `presenter_base.rb` file, I have something like this:

```
class PresenterBase

  def render_partial
    render(partial: "#{file_name}", locals: {presenter: self})
  end

  def render_form
    render_partial 'widgets/form'
  end

end
```

So, to render the form in a `FooPresenter`, I might do something like:

```
class FooPresenter < PresenterBase

  def present
    render_form
  end

  def form_path
    some_form_path(and: :maybe, some: :query_params)
  end

  def form_id
    'my-cool-form'
  end

  def form_classes
    'some cool classes'
  end

  def form_data
    {some: :form, data: :here}
  end

  def form_method
    :post
  end

  def form_inner
    ...
  end

end
```

Naturally, there's more to it than just that (like, how I get a plain old ruby object to `render`). But, that should give you a sense of one way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way if there are no complications and you follow the conventions, can be something like this

```
%form.search{ method: 'get', action: "/#{controller_name}/search" }
```

so if you are in users_controller, it will print "users", if you are in static_pages_controller, it will show "static_pages" and so on.